# Is there any way to restore driver from a Windows 7 installation CD?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

I've removed some standart Intel AHCI driver for C600 controller that came with Windows 7 installation. 
I can't find it on Intel site anywhere (I mean exactly this one). The driver that has been installed instead of it from MB drivers CD has a lot of flaws and doesn't work properly so now I'm using just universal AHCI driver from Microsoft.

Is there any way to restore that driver from a Windows 7 installation CD without reinstalling a system?

Comment: Have you tried running the Intel auto-driver updater? It will scan you machine and update chipsets/drivers accordingly. http://www.intel.com/p/en_US/support/detect

Comment: @TheD Yep. I've tried it and it's installing that defective RSTe driver.

Comment: If you had included the make/model of your computer... or in the case of a custom build, your motherboard make/model... I would have gone to the manufacturer's website to get the chipset drivers from there.  This way you are not relying on either the generic ones supplied by Microsoft, nor are you relying on trying to find them at Intel.  But, since only *you* have the manufacturer's information, only *you* can go to the manufacturer's support site for the drivers.

Answer (score 1):

Press the **start** button and then type **system restore** and select that option and then restore your system to an earlier point where it was working without any problem.

However you can use **system Restore** from windows itself but in any case you can't then follow the steps given below:

**1:** Insert the Windows 7 installation disc and restart the PC and press any key when prompted.

**2:** Select your language preferences and click on **Next**. Click on **Repair your computer**.

[image]

**3:** Select which operating system you want to restore and the click on Next.

**NOTE:** *If Windows 7 is not listed here, or it is blank, then it is ok. Click on Next anyway.*

**4:** Select the system recovery option you want to do.

[image]

Here you have to select the ***System Restore*** and then restore it on an earlier point. You will get back your system with your previous settings and drivers.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows installation CD only contains the Microsoft driver.

Comment: Actually you're wrong. If you go to the device manager and select some device, then update driver, then Browse my computer for driver software and then let me pick from a list you'll see a list of drivers that came not only from Microsoft or your installations. The thing is that you can also remove drivers that has been installed with OS that exactly what I did and it was bad idea after all.

Comment: @Regs They were not installed with the OS, but by your computer manufacturer.

Comment: I installed my Windows myself, and I see tons of non-Microsoft drivers. I can even got more of them through Windows Update. Unless you're still working on a very old Windows, you don't need to download as much drivers as back in the days.

Comment: @TomWijsman They are not written by Microsoft, but signed by Microsoft.

Comment: @kinokijuf: I did not state such thing, and that doesn't make it a Microsoft driver.

Comment: @TomWijsman I bet they were changed by Microsoft. For example, the MS driver for Broadcom wlan cards is called "BCM43XV" while the OEM one is called "BCM43XX". (the V stands for Vista I assume)

Comment: Just an increment in version, Windows did not change them...