# how do I figure out what app is trying to install when windows boots?

Tags: windows, boot, installer

I am using Windows 7 and every time it boots and application pops up with just a small dialog titled 'Windows InStaller" and hangs for forever and if i cancel it that hangs also.

How can I see what is causing this action and kill it?

Comment: If its "Windows Installer" then I think you tried somekind of update or any new software from Microsoft or any other software. If so then just try to login in safe mode and try to restore. If you can't go in safe mode either then see my [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/434995/is-there-any-way-to-restore-driver-from-a-windows-7-installation-cd/434999#434999) for restore windows.

Answer (score 1):

---

**You can do:** *if you cant do it in normal startup then do it in safe mode, for safe mode press rapidly F8 (in most cases) during boot time, to see list, and select Safe mode*

---

**Option 1**

**1st step** : Check whats there on startup,..
`Run > type msconfig > startup tab > deselect the ones that you think culprit.`
*Restart*

---

**2nd step** : Registry Tweaking (be careful)...
`RUN > type regedit > navigate to HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run > see if you find any new here, delete them`
*Restart*

---

**Option 2**
Use any good system maintenance tools like `Advance System care` (which i use), t has good free version and nice set of tools to.

---

*if you still cant solve it then , comment...*

Comment: Option 1 has worked for me in the past when I'd installed some drivers from HP that did exactly what Slee describes. Seemed to fix the problem nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer hangs at startup, there is no means of seeing what processes are running other than checking log files. You should boot in safe mode and run an antivirus program.

Comment: it is actually not hung